# Need help -  .net programming

Tags: .net, vb.net, expression

Im trying to configure a button in a .net healthcare application with the aid of a wizard that allows 3rd party integrations with other applications.

The process has been documented, including the scripting in a PDF document produced by the manufacturer (siemens) and distributed to me as an IT administrator.

Im now trying to configure the integration button and thankfully there is a test button as part of the wizard that verifys the script - which is returning the error:

> "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an
>   assignment"

I have no experience with programming so im hopefull some kind sole will give me some pointers:

here is the script:

> > Option Strict Off
> >
> > Imports System
> >
> > Imports System.Windows.Forms
>
> Module Script
>        Sub Main()
>           dim patientId as string
>           dim accessionNumber as string
>           dim parameters as string
>           dim strFiles as string
>
> ' get the patient ID and accession number from the currently
>     'selected row in the list of job search or advanced search
>
> patientId = ScriptApplication.GetValueFromContextServer(1)
>   accessionNumber = ScriptApplication.GetValueFromContextServer(2)
>
> strFiles =
>   (System.Environment.GetFolderPath(environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles))
>
> ```
>   'create command
>
>      Command = strFiles + "\Siemens\syngo\bin\ialauncher.exe"
>     'parameters = "-type READ -l SYNGOVIA\jbrea -p jbrea -a " + accessionNumber
>    parameters = "-type READ -lwwc -a"+ accessionNumber
> ```
>
> ' launch command
>
> ```
> System.diagnostics.process.start(command, parameters)  
>  End Sub
> ```
>
> End Module

the line below "create command" seems be be causing the problem. This is the executable that should launch, displaying the same patient in ialauncher.exe

Thanks in advance

\Flanders

Answer (score 3):

I added the missing code. I hope it helps. (Just delete the comment beside it.)

```
Option Strict Off

Imports System

Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module Script
Sub Main()
dim patientId as string
dim accessionNumber as string
dim parameters as string
dim strFiles as string
dim Command as string  'add this to your code.

' get the patient ID and accession number from the currently
'selected row in the list of job search or advanced search

patientId = ScriptApplication.GetValueFromContextServer(1)
accessionNumber = ScriptApplication.GetValueFromContextServer(2)

strFiles = (System.Environment.GetFolderPath(environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles))

  'create command

     Command = strFiles + "\Siemens\syngo\bin\ialauncher.exe"
    'parameters = "-type READ -l SYNGOVIA\jbrea -p jbrea -a " + accessionNumber
   parameters = "-type READ -lwwc -a"+ accessionNumber

' launch command

System.diagnostics.process.start(command, parameters)  
 End Sub 

End Module
```

Comment: Someone takes my answer four hours after I post it, reposts the original code with my answer in it, and they get the upvotes. I'm not sure what's funnier - that someone has the gall to do it, or that people can't see what happened and just hit the vote button without thinking.

Comment: Thankyou Jonners, you are a true gent, you will be the reason i have many browney points heading in my direction.

Comment: @PhilSanders my pleasure - just remember which answer to accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

What type is the Command variable? I bet it's not a String, which it should be.

It's not DIMensioned anywhere that I can see, so try adding

Dim Command As String

just below the Dim for strFiles.